# Matchstick Puzzle

Tags: matches

Move two matchsticks to make **2 E's**. (The Matchsticks cannot be stacked onto each other).
[image]

Comment: Can an E be oriented in reverse direction like $\exists$ ?

Comment: the person that asked this didn't give out hints

Comment: **the person that asked this didn't give out hints** - So this isn't your own puzzle, right?

Comment: or maybe like a 'm'?

Answer (score 2):

How about

> taking two bottom matches (one vertical and one horizontal) and placing them horizontally in between two top horizontal matches. It will make two overlapping Es.
>
>  Like this:
>
>  [image]

Comment: I'd actually even go as far to say there are 4 E's here.

Comment: @greenturtle3141, sure. But if want Es with the middle horizontal bar equidistant from the top and the bottom horizontal bars then there are only 2 Es.